# Can geometric programs be solved more efficiently than general convex optimization problems?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, geometric-programming

I want to solve an optimization problem for which I have already proven that it is feasible and convex. Introducing further variables and considering a special case of the problem, I can formulate it as geomtric programming problem.

Now I am wondering whether there is any advantage in having a geometric program. In [this](https://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/gp_tutorial.pdf) introduction to geometric programming it is only said that geometric programs are easy to solve, because it is possible to transfer them to convex optimization problems, which in turn can be solved efficiently.

However, considering that I already know that my problem is convex, do I gain anything, if I bring it down to the structure of a geometric program? I yes, how/why?

Comment: You must state the problem explicitly to hope for some advice...

Comment: My recollection is not solid enough to turn this into an answer. But it is my understanding that experiments have been done to compare the performance of NLP solvers on a non-convex GP, versus convex solvers on the transformed GP, and the latter proved superior. I think that's in part because convex solvers can take advantage of information about dual bounds that NLP solvers cannot (because they can't assume zero duality gap).

Comment: @AC_MOSEK: I eventually saw that I did a mistake in my transformation, so that I do not see a way to formulate my program as GP anymore (although the problem is still convex). However, the question is still of interest to me, because it is possible that I will run across the same issue later...

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks for your thoughts. However, the question was not convex solvers on tranformed GPs vs. NLP solvers on non-convex GPs, but general convex solvers applied to the transformed GP vs. convex solvers explicitely written for transformed GPs. That is, I wondered whether it is an advantage to transform my (already convex) problem into a GP.

Comment: Aha. No, if the problem is already convex I see no benefit to further transformation, particularly if it requires approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your alternative; I'm one of the [gpkit](http://gpkit.rtfd.org) developers, and in comparisons we've run GPs solve much faster than naive gradient descent (it's worth noting that not all GPs are convex without the transformation).

However, if your problem is can be solved by another convex solver (e.g. it's also a valid LP) then that solver is likely to be a little bit faster, because GP solvers are not as heavily developed as most other convex solvers.